Regex to capture form values in dotnet
I'm writing a custom model binder that will sometimes have to deal with forms. Those forms may have arrays as values.
I've been using this method
        private static async Task HandleFormAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var form = await httpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync();
            string jsonString = $"{{{string.Join(",", form.Select(x => $"\"{x.Key}\" : \"{x.Value}\""))}}}";


            try
            {
                var what = ProcessArray(jsonString);

                PagedRequest pagedRequest = what?.ToObject<PagedRequest>();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
                {
                    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                    return;
                }

                // Convert the form value to the target model type
                var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, bindingContext.ModelType);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
                return;
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
                // Deserialization failed, possibly due to invalid JSON
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                return;
            }
        }

It's not picking up array values though.
The json would be like this for example:
 {"filterList[0].filterType" : "contains","filterList[0].filterDataType" : "string","filterList[0].field" : "firstName","filterList[0].filterValue" : "bob","filterList[1].filterType" : "starts_with","filterList[1].filterDataType" : "string","filterList[1].field" : "lastName","filterList[1].filterValue" : "dylan","pageSize" : "15","pageNumber" : "1"}

Would  a regex do a better job parsing the array values?
I've tried this
 ["](?<arrayName>\w+\[\d+\])\.(?<propertyName>\w+)["]\s*[:]\s*["](?<value>.*?)["][,}]

But it's not matching the first value
Just the bold values
{"filterList[0].filterType" : contains,"filterList[0].filterDataType":"string","filterList[0].field" : "firstName","filterList[0].filterValue" : "bob","filterList[1].filterType" : "starts_with","filterList[1].filterDataType" : "string","filterList[1].field" : "lastName","filterList[1].filterValue" : "dylan"}
Any ideas how to approach this?

You receive a collection of key-value pairs, that is not JSON, you then build JSON out of it (poorly, without escaping the values), and then you use regex to parse that JSON? Maybe you should process the original collection instead? Your data does not contain arrays by the way (nor does the source data). It's just specially formatted names, with brackets in them, which is a convention recognized by the MVC model binder.

I was not asking what you were doing, I was describing what you were doing and wondering why.

@GSerg The reason I was doing it was because I was trying to make an attribute [FromFormOrBody] that would take in a form or a body and parse it in my ModelBinder based on the contentType

In your output in bold, at the end of your question, why isn't contains inside double quotes? Is this a copy-paste error in your question, or is it really what you have as raw JSON text? If the quotes are missing, then, effectively, the regex should be adapted to match a double-quoted string or a variable name / constant.

Just noticed that myself. It's a typo.

Personal thoughts
I'm not a .NET programmer, but I'm wondering why you need to convert
your form into some JSON to then parse it again. Can't you use this form
object to generate your model, without this JSON step?
Regarding your idea of using a regex
About the regex itself, you could have a go with this commented pattern
(using the x flag):
# JSON object key:
"(?:
  # A) An array with its index and child property.
  #    Example: "filterList[0].filterType"
  (?<arrayName>\w+\[(?<index>\d+)\])\.(?<propertyName>\w+)
  |
  # B) A simple key (not an array).
  #    Example: "pageSize" or "pageNumber"
  (?<simpleProperty>\w+)
)"
\s*:\s*          # Key and value separator.
"(?<value>.*?)"  # JSON object value:
\s*[,}]          # Separator or end of object.

PS: Syntax colouring above may be wrong as it doesn't detect what it is.
You'll have a better view and details here: https://regex101.com/r/vANW9d/1

Thanks @Patrick Janser, That will do it.  I was trying to build something that could handle forms and body so that the client can send the data whatever way suits them. Also FromForm gives me less usable info in my Swagger
